# What are good places to keep up with the Starcraft community?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'd like to stay up to date with Starcraft community developments.  I watch some Husky replays on youtube, so I know when MLG things happen, but don't know much about the actual league, how tournaments work, etc.

I would prefer good editorial content, such as "PlayerX was awesome at MLG", or "Zerg sucks cause...", or "Lower Protoss upgrades? WTF?"  Especially good discussion of how updates change/fix/break the game, how it would affect low level/high level play specifically, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to vote to close this question, as it's a "list of X"/website recommendation. There are problems with localization (any answer we give will be outdated as new websites appear/old ones disappear), problems with inaccurate voting schemes (people upvoting what they like rather than what is a good answer), and the fact that there is no single "right" answer to this. All answers are equally valid. If you have any other questions about what's on-topic here, please check out the [FAQ]!

Comment: :-(  I guess I was hoping there would be some sort of acknowledged reliable sources, like ESPN or the like for StarCraft.  I understand that this isn't the place for questions like I want to have answered, but was hoping it could direct me to reasonable, good sources, which could be objective, compared to "best" sources, which are absolutely subjective.  Is there any modification for the question to make it appropriate?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 communities that are up-to-date on the Starcraft Scene:

- [Team Liquid](http://www.teamliquid.net)
- [SC2 Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/)

Team Liquid has been more of a sturdy place for strategy and discussion while Reddit is more of a "omg that was cool!" Kind of thing.

From your question, Team Liquid seems like a better fit for what you are looking for.

Comment: I've poked around teamliquid a little bit, and my issue with it is that it that it is a little untamed.  I feel like it's lots of opinions from the entire internet and I have no idea who would be a more credible source.  I don't necessarily want to keep up with an entire forum.  I would prefer a blog format kind of thing.  Something more curated.  Maybe I can get that from TL, but just don't quite understand it?

Comment: It is kinda difficult because there are so many topics/threads created every day. My trick is that I visit both, I pay attention to the "Community News and Headlines" on TL and just browse the "what's hot" section on Reddit. It's a pretty good mix. Team Liquid is also handy for their "upcoming events" and player streams sections.

Comment: @E-Rock Have you tried http://wellplayed.org?

Answer (score 1):

If you look for post-event discussion, opinions about how playstyles changed (and will/should) in different matchups and upcoming patches, then you really should watch/listen some [State of the Game](http://sotg-sc2.blogspot.com/) podcast episodes:

> No idea what the hell State of the Game is? **It is a podcast based around the happenings of the SC2 world(*).** The Pillars of State of the Game [fancy way of saying the hosts]:
>    JP **'itmeJP'** McDaniel, Sean **'Day[9]'** Plott, Dan **'Artosis'** Stemkoski, Tyler **'Liquid`Tyler'** Wasieleski and Geoff **'EGiNcontroL'** Robinson

Most informative site I know for this is the [Official State of the Game Podcast Thread](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=145494) on TeamLiquid.
Recently they tend to invite some other persons to the talk, these are players (Destiny, NaNiWa, HuK, White-Ra,...) or other important community guys e.g. the manager of Complexity Gaming, some TL-staffies or people who make StarCraft-related documentaries.

I usually find time to listen to it every week when walking or sitting in the bus. And most of the time its **hilarious to listen** to these guys!

Comment: Wow.  Day9, Artosis, and Incontrol in one podcast?  I'm a newb with this, but that sounds great.

Comment: I don't wanna hype or advertise too much, but make yourself ready for some ironic trollfests of sarcasm, all I say: Incontrol vs Artosis or Horses... :D